# Link private github repository to potential employer

Tags: github

I have some private github repos that contains the work that I am most proud of. I would like potential employers to see this code. Is it possible for me to give them a link to the private repository so they can view my work?

Answer (score 3):

You could either:

- create a private repo in bitbucket and push your project there, then send an invitation to employers' emails
- add potential employers as collaborators to your private Github repo.

  - On the main repo's page, go to the "Settings" tab
  - On the nav links to the right, "Collaborators"

I'd recommend against zipping the project and sending them the whole thing, as they'd either not see the git history, or see your entire git configuration, depending on how you zip the folder... And I think seeing how a developer works with git is important in addition to seeing the code itself...

Answer (score -1):

There are few option for you:

1. If you have private repositary on your machine, then public into bitbucket or github and making private repo.
2. If you have private repositary online you can invite them to the repositary and give them privilages that you want to.
3. Make latest backup of your repositary and send it to them.

Hope it helps.